# Do PDO and MySQLi use MySQL functions under the abstraction layer?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysqli

*Disclaimer: this question is strictly about mysql and database abstraction layers that support it.*

The PHP website notes that using the `mysql_` functions of PHP is highlighy discouraged. It instead encourages developers to use `PDO` or `MySQLi`.

Here's my question: in regards to mysql, under all the abstraction, are PDO and MySQLi just being a safer, more object-oriented wrapper for the `mysql_` functions?

And if that's true, aren't frameworks like CodeIgniter and Symfony creating an unnecessary amount of wrappage by putting a layer on top of MySQLi which would then put a layer on top of native PHP `mysql_`?

If it isn't true, I want to know why an experienced developer is discouraged from using `mysql_` and what `PDO` and `MySQLi` actually do under the abstraction.

(Also, please don't tell me to go look at the code) Will give +100 bounty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Here's my question: in regards to mysql, under all the abstraction, are PDO and MySQLi just being a safer, more object-oriented wrapper for the mysql_ functions?

No. Like xdazz said, both MySQLi and PDO are implemented in C, which means they don't just wrap the mysql_* functions.

> And if that's true, aren't frameworks like CodeIgniter and Symfony creating an unnecessary amount of wrappage by putting a layer on top of MySQLi which would then put a layer on top of native PHP mysql_?

There's another reason to consider: CodeIgniter and Symfony probably created an interface over the default interface, because the default interface isn't usable enough (from their point of view). I myself have written a layer over PDO which sets some default settings (such as error-mode, as PDO is quiet by default) and makes a more intuitive API altogether. PDO is a very decent piece of software, but the `setAttribute( $attr, $value )` just isn't my cup of tea, really.

Answer (score 2):

`PDO` and `MySQLi` fucnctions and class methods are bindings to C-level API. Generally it is recommended to use this functions because of prepared statements: [in PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php), [in MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Using prepared statements is a good way to prevent SQL injections.

Answer (score 1):

No, PDO and MySQLi are not wrapper of `mysql_` functions, they are implemented in C level, different extensions.

Just think, if they are wrappers, `--with-mysqli` and so on is not necessary.